# Kali Linux Xfce menu modification

Tags: kali-linux

I'm building a custom Kali Linux ISO within Kali environment. I want to completely change the main menu structure/replace the existing Kali's and to add my own programs. I kept only Maltego from the original Kali installation, so I I needed to modify kali-maltego.desktop and assigned it a new menu .directory. However, with every sudo apt update, my customization is overwritten.

I have deleted all Kali menu directories in /usr/share/desktop-directories, and added mine. I also changed menu structure in /etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/kali-applications.menu. but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Removing those files is definitely not the way to go. Usually it's not a good idea to mess with the package system (in this case externally removing files installed by it).

In a distribution using software conforming to [Free desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org), Desktop files inside the user's home file structure take precedence over the same desktop files in the system-wide directories. This can be taken advantage of by copying all the desktop files (from the apps you want to remove from the menu) to your user's home file structure and then modifying those copied files, that now belong to the user, by adding a line that will hide them from the menu.

In those distributions something along these lines should work to hide the application `XYZ` from the user's menu:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/XYZ.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then, at the end of `~/.local/share/applications/XYZ.desktop` this line should be added `NoDisplay=true`.

Restart the user's session and `XYZ` should no longer be in the menu. Other users will still have it. And that will survive upgrades.

More information on how that works, and also some alternatives can be found in [*Tips and tricks*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries#Tips_and_tricks) in the ArchWiki page about desktop entries.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have read all the discussion regarding menu edit on Kali but I couldn't get the answer I am looking for. I would like to have such a menu structure for all users, i.e not only for my session. I am looking for a solution for a system wide, not only me. As far as I understand by "cp /usr/share/applications/XYZ.desktop ~/.local/share/applications " I am only editing the menu for myself but not system wide?